# One "Faster" server slower than the other

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have 2 VMs:

- VM1 - 8cores 32gb RAM
- VM2 - 8cores 64gb RAM

I'm running identical process on both VMs at same time using SSIS Catalog, all processes are executed on it's own VM so no information travels through the network.. Aaaand I found out that load times for these processes are quite slower on VM2.

Load:

- VM1- 15m
- VM2- 45m

I have checked some performance metrics and did some basic tests... During the load I can see Network I/O Waits

- VM1- 600ms/sec
- VM2- 750ms/sec

I assume this network I/O wait comes from SSIS as SSIS is executing a query against SQL Server and then inserting the information in batchs, waits statistics tells me that both cases wait type is ASYNC_NETWORK_IO.

Also I did a test using SP_SPACEUSED to see the amount of rows inserted in both tables at same time and the results are not super accurated but VM1 almost doubles the amount of rows inserted...

Any further tests I'm missing? Any other checks that comes to your mind?

Comment: Are both vms on  the same physical box? Is the storage for both vms the same? There are many reasons one vm is slower than another and it's hard to tell without information about the underlying hardware

Comment: Also this information is hard to get for me as welll... However, I know that VMs are not in the same box and Disk is not the same, one VM is classified as UAT and other as DEV so disk is also different. My main concern relies in the disk being slower in VM2, I will try to run IO tests...

Comment: There's no point in comparing performance then is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running in a virtualized environment so just because a server has more virtual RAM or more vCPU's doesn't mean it's "faster" (as you call it).

Several factors are abstracted by the virtualization layer and you would need to know and even benchmark them all.

For example, there is no guarantee the storage underneath the vmdk's is anywhere near comparable, so you would need to benchmark the storage and monitor it on a physical level.

The underlying physical CPU's could make a huge difference too. How fast are the physical processors? Are the CPU's overcommitted in the virtualization layer (i.e. are more vCPU's assigned per physical core) etc.
You could look at the CSTP or RDY values in VMWare among other things.

It really isn't possible to call one server faster than another because it has more virtual resources if you don't know the underlying hardware and virtualization configuration.

Some things you could check are

- Storage performance
- vCPU/pCPU ratio (overcommitting resources)
- The vm's running on the same box (you might not know what your neighbour is doing unless you get access to the VMWare/Hyper-V counters such as esxtop CSTP and RDY values).
- NUMA setup on the VM layer
- power settings and hyperthreading configuration in the bios of the underlying machines to make sure they perform well when not fully stressed (like they are when running benchmarks)
- ...

I hope some of these pointers can help you troubleshoot further, but without any hard evidence about the underlying hardware there really isn't any point in comparing the virtual resource configuration to determine which VM should be "faster"

That being said, you may get some mileage looking at perfmon counters to determine disk latency or cpu load, or even use some VMWare counters such as effective speed in MHz or stolen time and you could get some information from wait stats but I still think getting access to some information about the VM configuration and underlying hardware is essential.

If you can, benchmark the underlying hardware.

Comment: The NUMA point by Tom is important and not easy to figure out. If your VM's memory allocation crosses NUMA nodes, perf can be considerably slower even if you have more allocated memory. This affects database workloads significantly more than others. SQL Server has optimizations to work within the same node as much as possible but when running in a VM, it won't actually know so you take the perf hit silently. One possible hint might be the same logical read (off memory) having much higher latency.

Comment: This is just a perfect explanation Tom, thank you very much, will try to collect all this information and also test the Storage Performance. I can only say thank you again :)